# nested table operations

Tags: sql, oracle

I made a nested table in which I store names and surnames. One name has two surnames.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE list_surname AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
/
CREATE TABLE person (name varchar2(10), 
surname list_surname)
NESTED TABLE surname STORE AS list;
/ 

INSERT INTO person VALUES('Olsen', list_surname('Arthur', 'Baxter'));
INSERT INTO person VALUES('Jensen', list_surname('Barney', 'Louis'));
INSERT INTO person VALUES('Andersen', list_surname('Chase', 'Mason'));
/
```

Now I want to make an anonymous block to count and display how many people have even one surname that contains the letter 'u' and if that person has the letter 'u' in his surname then I want to print that person (name + surnames). This is what I made so far:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
v_var VARCHAR2(32);
v_nr NUMBER(30);
cursor c1 (var VARCHAR2) is
  select regexp_count(var,'[u]',1,'i') from dual;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN person.FIRST .. person.LAST LOOP
      v_nr := 0;
      open c1(person.list_surname);
      loop
         fetch c1 into v_nr;
         exit when c1%notfound;
         IF v_nr > 0 THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(person);
         end if;
       end loop;
       close c1;
    end loop;
END;
/
```

I'm not really good at working with nested tables because this is my first time. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
   v_var   VARCHAR2 (32);
   v_nr    NUMBER (30) := 0;

   CURSOR c_name
   IS
      SELECT name FROM person;

   CURSOR c_surname (p_name person.name%TYPE)
   IS
      SELECT VALUE (c) sn
        FROM THE (SELECT surname
                    FROM person
                   WHERE name = p_name) c;
BEGIN
   FOR cur IN c_name
   LOOP
      FOR cs IN c_surname (cur.name)
      LOOP
         IF INSTR (cs.sn, 'u') > 0
         THEN
         v_nr := v_nr + 1;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               cur.name || ' ' || cs.sn);
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line('Total Count: '||v_nr);
END;
/
```